# Finding the Minimum Interval of root Equation (Numerical Analysis)

Tags: analysis, polynomials

Im New to Numerical Analysis I got a problem I don't understand the problem. I got a Question.

Q: The Minimum interval in which root of the equation $x^2+3x-1=0$ lie is

Options:

1) $(0,1)$

2) $(1,2)$

3) $(2,4)$

4) $(0,2)$

I think option $1$ is correct But I have doubt Please help me to explain this problem.

Comment: Instead of given negative post. Please let me know the solution

Comment: @Kumar Bro, If you know the answer please comment

Comment: No I have no idea

Comment: Yes, Actually I'm very weak in maths thats why I'm asking. Can you please explain it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test Please do visit the mentioned link.

Comment: Thanks But I dont understand why I need to check this. I dont understand anything there.

Comment: My bad... But you haven't mentioned any of the background details about your knowledge of the problem. I assumed some background in pre-calculus and tried to giving you the best possible link that might be helpful to do numerical analysis. Thereby, Please write out the background of your knowledge about the problem.

Comment: I have background of Computer Science. But Im very weak in Maths, So yes No Idea about Differentiation.

Comment: Is the solution Helpful? And does it meets your requirements?

Comment: I'm sure you mean $x^2-3x+1$ as all of the roots are positive in that equation ([Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)).

Comment: Hey @desmos Thanks for the message. I checked the question again Its actually $x^2+3x-1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**
Assuming that OP has a background about *solving linear equations in two variables* and approximately, calculating the square roots of the natural numbers.

**Answer:**
Given equation: $x^2+3x-1=0$
Now, $$x^2+2*\frac{3}{2}*x+\frac{9}{4}=(\frac{9}{4}+1)\\\implies (x+\frac{3}{2})^2=\frac{13}{4}\\\implies x+\frac{3}{2}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{13}{4}}\\\implies x+\frac{3}{2}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}\\x=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{13}}{2}$$So, It is easy to see that both the roots/solutions of the equation are negative.

Now, Let $$x_1=\frac{-3-\sqrt{13}}{2}\enspace \text{and}\enspace x_2=\frac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\\\implies x_2-x_1=\sqrt{13}$$
Observe that $3<\sqrt{13}<4$.
Hence, Both the solutions lie in a minimum interval of $(2,4)$.
Thus, Option $3$ is **Correct.**

Comment: Sorry, I got confused last time.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer But I have a question..
 with the first line Can you Please explain this?
x2+2∗32∗x+(54+1)=54

Comment: from where 3/2 and 5/4 came? can you please explain?

Comment: @GhayyasMubashir I wanted to use the identity: $(a+b)^2=a^2+2*a*b+b^2$. and $\frac{5}{4}+1=\frac{9}{4}=(\frac{3}{2})^2$

Comment: Sorry I think I wrote the wrong Question. I checked the question again. Its Actually  $x^2 + 3x - 1 = 0 $

Comment: @GhayyasMubashir The correct Question should be: "The smallest interval in which the roots of the Equation $x^2+3x-1=0$ lies". The word "**Minimum**" represents the difference between the roots and then mapping the difference to he appropriate given option interval. :)